# Como delimitar um campo de telefone (Oracle DataBase)

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, oracle11g

Bom dia,

Galera estou precisando de uma ajuda para delimitar o campo de telefone no meu banco de dados, sendo mais especifico, se hoje alguém digitar um numero de telefone com 4 dígitos (por exemplo) esse telefone será salvo, eu preciso que seja aceito somente números entre 8 e 9 dígitos, estou usando o Oracle 11g.

Comment: Isso não pode ser feito na aplicação? Você tem que tratar no BD?
Da pra usar uma `trigger` de `before insert`, se realmente precisar fazer no BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser criar uma check constraint.

Por exemplo

```
ALTER TABLE  CLIENTES
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_CLIENTES_TEL
  CHECK (TELEFONE IS NULL OR LENGTH(TRIM(TELEFONE)) IN (8,9));
```

Aqui por exemplo irá se permitir telefone nulo , cliente não tem não telefone , etc,  mas se preenchido deverá ter tamanho de 8 ou 9.

Comment: Então cara eu estava tentando algo BEM parecido porém não com a mesma sintaxe e estava obtendo um erro, fazendo dessa maneiro que você descreve eu recebo o seguinte erro: ORA-02293 não é possível validar (chk_clientes) - restrição de verificação violada

Comment: E que devem existir valores no campo TELEFONE que violam a CONSTRAINT , 'limpe" estes campos antes de criar a mesma.